# Have the tag counters stopped working again?

Tags: discussion, bug

Have the tag counters stopped working?
[image]

I know this happened a while back but wondered if it has occurred again.

I have had a few upvotes on SQL recently and believe the counter should be on 600+, however it remains at 597 for the last few days.  I have received no down votes.

Comment: I do not know about your timezone, I am from India and these counter get refreshed at my morning time 8:30 am each day.

Comment: @Kedarnath - I'm UTC - however I believe the counter has not increased for the last couple of days.

Comment: Well it is automated activity, It should work properly, Lets wait for tomorrow's 8:30 my time, which will be 3:00 am UTC

Comment: [Data.SE seems to support this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/170292/score-per-tag) knowing it updates on Mondays and you have gained SQL votes since then.

Comment: @DarrenDavies, Its 8:46 am at mine place, but still the counter is not refreshed  in your profile, Now I agree with you that, it is a bug. +1