# Why is there a difference between the badge votes on the Stack Exchange Android app and desktop Stack Overflow page

Tags: support, badges, android-app, tag-score

I notice that the Android Stack Exchange app shows my SO [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) tags have upvote scores of 111 and 103 respectively but via my desktop browser it shows that I have 108 and 100 respectively.
This difference has lasted for over 4 days, is there a lag or difference in the calculation? All other tags have correct scores and number of answers posted.

Comment: There seems to be an ongoing issue with tag score recalc: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225100/have-the-tag-counters-stopped-working-again and caching as always....

Comment: @rene is this a general issue or is this more specfic to the app?

Comment: I'm not sure, it might be related though.

Comment: @rene maybe but this doesn't necessarily explain the discrepancy between the app and desktop browser sites as it looks like the update has already occurred and the mobile appears to be being updated by the updated and correct server

Comment: We have to wait and see if a dev wants to clearify what is going on...

Comment: It must be _caching_. After all, caching is  the _Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything_.